# Mysql select unique columns from where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, clause

I'm trying to see if it's possible to have several unique columns in a select statement from varying where clause selections.  Here is my query.

```
select org_id, count(org_role) as total
from organization
where org_id = 10 and org_role = 9
group by org_id;
```

the above works perfectly.  It produces:

```
org_id   total
```

```
10        19
```

Id'd like to add another column count named total2 where org_id = 10 and org_role = 7 (the count is 23).  So i'd have this result:

```
org_id    total    total2
```

```
10        19         23
```

I'm just not sure how to edit the original above query to produce that.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just add (+) the two columns in a new one in the select.

Comment: not sure i''m following.  could you copy my query and show what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. For example:

```
select
  org_id,
  sum(case when org_role = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as total,
  sum(case when org_role = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as total2
from organization
where org_id = 10 and org_role in (7, 9)
group by org_id;
```

Comment: great suggestion.  feel like i'm close.  just now that's giving me an error FUNCTION sum does no exist, Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: @sean The query does not have a syntax problem. See example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oehkx9JiEjEbpCnM3rwhTg/0

Comment: Hello.  Oh i wasn't doubting the integrity of the query.  It should work fine i don't doubt.  I'm just getting that error still.  We do have an older version of MySQL.  It's version 6 and i think the latest version  is at least 8 now.  Maybe i can find a way to upgrade and see if that clears the issue.  Let me try that.

Comment: @sean For the sake of completeness, it does work in MySQL 5.6 as well. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oehkx9JiEjEbpCnM3rwhTg/1 Can you reproduce the case in a fiddle?

Comment: you guys are great.   thanks for all your help with this.  the problem is OBVIOUSLY me :) .  I've never used Fiddle before but love the examples you created.   I'd certainly be happy to try.  Let me take a look.  It's fun to learn : )

Comment: so the below worked using SUM.  so it has be just be something weird going on. 

select
  org_id,  sum(org_role)
from organization
where org_id = 10 and org_role = 9
group by org_id;

so i know SUM works on my end, just have to see why it's not working for the desired query.  playing with it now.

Comment: it's FIXED !!!  And works like a beautiful charm.  SO awesome to have gotten this.   So, turns out, it was all my fault.   And lesson learned.  The issue was i had a space between both SUMs and the parenthesis.  I just did not notice that.  and that alone produced that error 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual'.  As soon as i removed the space, problem solved.  THANKS A BUNCH SIR.  This was perfect !!

Answer (score 0):

```
select org_id, count(org_role) as total, count(total_2)
from organization
where org_id = 10 and org_role = 9
group by org_id;
```

If it does not work please send your database structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  i'd have to get some help with sending you the structure.  In order for count(total_2) to be valid , i''d need a way to point it to a different qualifying line of where org_id = 10 and org_role = 7 .  the first count correctly gets it's total from the where clause, i need the second count to point to org_id = 10 and org_role = 7, giving me 2 different totals of the two different org_roles.